# Split & Extract date (Free form writing) and hours mentioned as numbers into separate columns - R

Tags: r, date, data-manipulation, lubridate

I have an input

```
            **ID**        **Input Text**
            1         08/18/2017 8 hours
            2         08/14/2017-10HRS
            3         8/28/17 through 9/1/17 8 hrs per day
            4         08/17/17-6hrs
            5         08/14/2017-8hrs 08/15/2017-8hrs 08/16/2017-8hrs
            6         7.27.2017 -8 hrs, 8.3.2017 8 hours, 8.14.2017 8hrs
            7         08/16/2017 7 hours 10 minutes
            8         8 hrs - 07/11/2017 and 8 hrs 07/12/2017
            9         08/14/17-8hrs // 08/15/17-8hrs
            10        08/14/2017- 7:45 hrs// 08/15/2017- 7:45 hrs//
            11        Wed,  8/16/17 …. Cx missed 6 hrs on 8/14/17… missed 8 hrs on 8/15/17
            12        08/10/2017     8 hrs 
            13        08/11/2017      2 hrs 
            14        08/16/2017      8 hrs
            15        08/07/2017- 4 hours missed- Doctors appt , 08/13/2017 8 hours - Incapacity ,      08/15/2017 -8 hours- Incapacity , 08/16/2017 -3 hours // Doctor
            16        Aug 1, 2017 – 7.75 hours
            17        Aug 2, 2017 – 1.75 hours
            18        Aug 3, 2017 – 3 hours
            19        Aug 4, 2017 – 4 hours
            20        Aug 7, 2017 – 7.75 hours
```

Expected output is:

[image: Expected output should have the date and the hours mentioned split]]

So far, I tried to split the input text in hopes to convert the column into date using lubridate, but unable to

```
dt$Date_lubridate <- mdy(dt$Time)

Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Wanted to split the column to date and number separately and then convert column the date column to date using lubridate, but I'm stuck due to the variation of date format.

```
x<-dt$Time

sc1 <- sub("\\-.*", "", x)

sc2 <- sub('.*-', '', x)

sc3 <- sub("\\ .*", "", x)

fstat <- cbind.data.frame ("ID" = dt$ID, "Actual" = x, "Date" = sc1, "time" = sc2, "time2" = sc3)
```

Tried using on sc1:

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(x = sc1,
                orders = c("d m y", "d B Y", "m/d/y"),
                locale = "eng")
```

but due to the variations I get parsing error.

I think I'm all over the place, since I'm missing some basic manipulations any nudge/help towards the right  direction would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the part of the dates that you want, then convert them with `mdy()`.

```
library(stringr)

regDate = "([A-Z][a-z]{2}|\\d{1,2})( |\\/|\\.)\\d{1,2}(,|\\/|\\.) ?\\d{2,4}"
str_extract(dt$Time, regDate) %>% unlist() %>% lubridate::mdy()
```

using the dplyr pipes for a bit of convenience there at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much!! awesome. This solves my first part of the problem!!

Comment: @MrRj If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: while your answer solved the first part of my problem, stil waiting for some direction on how to separate the numeric hour and other dates. Since there are multiple dates in one line for example in Row 5, 8, 9, 10. I up voted your answer though

Comment: Ok. I know you can use regex to remove the matches to the first date part, but there's still a lot of variability in the entries.